# In MapBasic, how do I open a connection to MapMarker so I can allow my app to geocode?

Tags: mapbasic

I would like my app to open up MapMarker and automatically geocode for me.  I cannot get past the Open Connection statement as I am receiving an error while compiling.  Here is the code:

```
Include "mapbasic.def"

Dim CnctNum As Integer
CnctNum = 1

Open Connection into Variable CnctNum Service Geocode MapMarker
Interactive off
```

The error that I am receiving says "Found [interactive] while searching for [url]."  I am only looking to connect to MapMarker so I am not sure why I am receiving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to specify an URL for your MapMarker service. I can see from the syntax that it's not that clear that you have to, but you do.

I think the syntax should look more like this:

```
Open Connection Service
    { Geocode [ MapMarker | Envinsa ] | Isogram } 
    URL URLstring 
    [ User name_string [ Password pwd_string ] ] 
    [ Interactive [ On | Off ] ]
     into variable var_name
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I have asked our documentation to imrpove the help on this topic. Should be fixed with the upcoming version 12.0